# Perl RegExp remove img tag if content style parameter

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have a `Perl` RegExp question. Given this HTML code:

```
<a href="#"><img src="..." alt="..." title="..."></a>
<a href="#"><img src="..." alt="..." style="display: none;" title="..."></a>
<a href="#"><img src="..." alt="..." title="..." style="display: none;"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="..." style="display: none;" alt="..." title="..."></a>
<a href="#"><img style="display: none;" src="..." alt="..." title="..."></a>
```

How can I remove all `img` tags with their parent `a` if the img contain this string?

```
style="display: none;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html =~ s|<a\s+href[^>]*>\s*<img[^>]*style="display: none;"[^>]*>\s*</a>||g
```

This is checking the `img` tag inside the `a` tag. And also checking whether the given `style` attribute resides inside the `img` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...:

```
if ($html =~ /(<a href="#"><img style="display:\s*none;".*?<\/a>)/g) {
    remove($1);
}
```